# Unresolved aar resources

Tags: android, kotlin, resources, build.gradle, aar

I'm building a custom multi-project hierarchy of Android libraries shared in multiple apps.
For example:
[image]

In my APPs I can correctly use both Kotlin Class and xml resouces of implemented aars.

In my second-level libraries (e.g. Library D) I can correctly use Kotlin Class of compileOnly first-level aars (e.g. Library A). I can also correctly use xml resources from first-level aars only in seconds level xml resources. For example:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/MY-COLOR-FROM-1-LEVEL-AAR"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />
```

It works.

But I cannot use the same resource in Kotlin classes. Example:

```
someView.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.MY-COLOR-FROM-1-LEVEL-AAR))
```

give me "Unresolved reference".

In the second-level libraries (e.g. Library D) build.gradle I import first-level libraries (e.g. Library A) using:

```
compileOnly files('libs/LibraryA.aar')
```

What's the problem ?

Comment: Hi, did you checked R class import? It must be from library, where is that resource, e.g. `com.libraryA.R.color.MY-COLOR-FROM-1-LEVEL-AAR`.

Comment: @MirekHýbler yes, I try, but it give me error unresolved reference with the "R" highlighted in red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several test I found the solution. In *gradle.properties* file of second-level project (in this example case Library D) simply change

```
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
```

to

```
android.nonTransitiveRClass=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Enables namespacing of each library's R class so that its R class includes only the resources declared in the library itself and none from the library's dependencies, thereby reducing the size of the R class for that library

change value of this flag

```
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
```

to

```
android.nonTransitiveRClass=false
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the R class of the aar cannot be imported?